# Microsoft Flow: How to Concatenate Data from JSON Object

Tags: json, concatenation, power-automate

I have a REST Web Services Call that is returning data in the following format:

```
{
    "Id": "0497cee4-45dc-47d8-97a8-b45ad8018775",
    "Status": "OK",
    "ProviderName": "MyApp",
    "DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1508348383277)/",
    "Contacts": [
        {
            "ContactID": "1efa0ea1-de5c-4172-869c-816e27c3c825",
            "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "Name": "Company",
            "FirstName": "Joe",
            "LastName": "Bob",
            "EmailAddress": "mainguy@here.com",
            "BankAccountDetails": "",

            "ContactPersons": [
                {
                    "FirstName": "Operations",
                    "LastName": "",
                    "EmailAddress": "there@here.com",
                    "IncludeInEmails": true
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "Another",
                    "LastName": "Contact Email",
                    "EmailAddress": "here@there.com",
                    "IncludeInEmails": true
                }
            ],
            "HasAttachments": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Within Microsoft Flow I would like to grab the main contact email (Contacts.EmailAddress) as well as all of the secondary Contacts Emails (Contacts.ContactPersons[x].EmailAddress); and use that for the too field of down-flow email.

ContactPersons will not always be defined in every case, but Contacts.EmailAddress should be.

What is the best way to do this with a flow? Is there a way to concatenate data over a loop or something? I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Data Operations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/data-operations).

You can start off with a **Select**, picking the EmailAddress field in the Map, and then redirecting that to a **Join** and using that output.